# pip3 install h5py is not working in mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, h5py

Even after successful installation of h5py using pip3, executing `python3 -c "import h5py"` gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h5py'
```

But installing through easy_install is getting the h5py module for python2.7 instead of python3.

So what exactly is the issue and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 11):

Without specifying the hdf5's version, you can install h5py like below.

```
brew install hdf5
export HDF5_DIR=$(brew --prefix hdf5)
pip install h5py
```

Answer (score 7):

based off the [docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/2.3/build.html) do a brew install like this.

```
$ brew install hdf5
```

Then install h5py preferably using conda

```
$ conda install h5py
```

or, with pip

```
$ pip3 install h5py
```

Comment: `brew install hdf5` is done and I am not using anaconda package, wanted to install with pip3

Comment: Working like a charm! this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Without using conda, the following steps work for me:

```
$ brew install hdf5
$ export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.0_4
$ pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py
```

Comment: Finally that worked. Thanks! I didn't use the `--no-binary` flag though.

Comment: This worked for me. The other solution did not.

Comment: I also needed `export CPATH="/opt/homebrew/include/"`